# event.stopPropagation overrides event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a Javascript code to close modals when user clicks outside the modals.
This is the code:

```
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modalo) {
        modalo.style.display = "none";
    } else if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    } else if (event.target == yesnomodal) {
        yesnomodal.style.display = "none";
    } else if (event.target == errmodal) {
        errmodal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This code works until another code that is used to display some popups when user clicks some button is added. The code is:

```
var x = document.getElementById("bell_svg_dropdown_menu");
var y = document.getElementById("home_svg_dropdown_menu");

function bellSvgDropdown(t) {
    if (t && x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
        y.className = y.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    } else {
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
}

function homeSvgDropdown(t) {
    if (t && y.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        y.className += " w3-show";
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    } else {
        y.className = y.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Now, the popups are displayed but the modals cannot be closed by clicking outside the modals. My observation is that `event.stopPropagation` overrides `event.target`. How should I rewrite my code to solve this?

The HTML for the popups is:

```
<div class="inline_block">
                <div style="display:inline-block; margin:6.5px; position:relative;" class="">
                    <div class="w3-dropdown-click">
                        <svg onclick="homeSvgDropdown(true)" fill="#20b2aa" height="40" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10">
                                <div id="" class="in_svg_notification">5</div>
                            </foreignObject>
                            <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z"/>
                            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                        </svg>
                        <div id="home_svg_dropdown_menu" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border" style="width: 350px;">
                            <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Customer 1 wants to rent</a>
                            <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Customer 2 wants to rent</a>
                            <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Customer 3 wants to rent</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display:inline-block; margin:6.5px; position:relative;" class="">
                    <div class="w3-dropdown-click">
                        <svg onclick="bellSvgDropdown(true)" fill="#20b2aa" height="40" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10">
                                <div id="" class="in_svg_notification">5</div>
                            </foreignObject>
                            <path d="M12 22c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2h-4c0 1.1.89 2 2 2zm6-6v-5c0-3.07-1.64-5.64-4.5-6.32V4c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67-1.5 1.5v.68C7.63 5.36 6 7.92 6 11v5l-2 2v1h16v-1l-2-2z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <div id="bell_svg_dropdown_menu" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border" style="width: 350px;">
                            <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Customer 1 wants to rent</a>
                            <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Customer 2 wants to rent</a>
                            <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Customer 3 wants to rent</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the HTML for one of the modals is:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
                    <div id="myModalSignUp" class="modal">

                        <!-- Modal content -->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <span class="close1">&times;</span>
                            <div style="font-size:30px; font-weight:bold; color:#008B8B;">Register as owner..</div>

                            <div style="margin:auto; margin-bottom:20px;">
                                <form class="" action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
                                    <div><input class="modalin" type="text" placeholder="First name"></div>
                                    <div><input class="modalin" type="text" placeholder="Middle name"></div>
                                    <div><input class="modalin" type="text" placeholder="Last name"></div>
                                    <div><input class="modalin" type="tel" placeholder="Phone" pattern="([0]{1}[6|7]{1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7})?"></div>
                                    <div style="line-height:22px; padding:8px 5%; font-size:12.5px;">By clicking Join now, you agree to the <b>Brentles</b> User Agreement, Privacy Policy, and Cookie Policy.</div>
                                    <div style="line-height:0px;"><input class="modal_sign_btn" type="submit" value="Enter"></div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

The modals javascript is preceded by this codes:

```
    // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: can you provide HTML also?

Comment: There is a great article regarding effect of  stopPropagation() [Link] (https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/).

Comment: @Deepakgupta Yes;

Comment: @Deepakgupta - edit successful.. HTML codes added

Comment: _“My observation is that event.stopPropagation overrides event.target”_ - I doubt that is actually what is going on. Sounds more like you are handling a different event than the one you think you do (_that_ possibly due to the fact that something else stopped a certain event from propagating.)